# How do I create pagination with AJAX in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#conteudo").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $( this ).attr('href');
        $('#paginacao a').load(href +'#conteudo');
    });
});
```

---

```
<ul id="paginacao">
            <li><a href="index.html">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="pagina2.html">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is not working, what's missing?
HELP!

Comment: Please don't forget to mention the framework you're working with whenever you do (I edited the tags of this question to reflect yours). 
This is important since the tag filtering system of stackoverflow relies on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound to the UL element itself. You should be binding to the links (A)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#conteudo a").click(function( e ){
       e.preventDefault();
       var href = $( this ).attr('href');
       $('#paginacao a').load(href +'#conteudo');
   });
});
```

Also, this bit of code

```
       $('#paginacao a').load(href +'#conteudo');
```

Are you attempting to load the contents of the AJAX call into the link? Shouldn't you be loading it into a separate container?

Comment: How? Sorry but I do not know much about AJAX

Comment: If you want the contents of the AJAX call to appear in a different place, create a new DIV and give the `.load()` function the ID of that instead of having `paginacao`.